# Where is Java Main method defined in source?

Tags: program-entry-point, java

Pardon me for asking this silly question. Where can i find java main method definition in java source? it is not in object class or system class? so how and where is it defined exactly?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

Comment: We ourselves give the definition for main(), don't we?

Comment: Are you asking where the C program is started?

Comment: My question is simple. You cannot keep java's entry method as main1 instead of main method. Atleast where is that handled?

Comment: And i cant find Main method definition in any javadoc API which means it may be handled natively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is Java Main method defined in source?

It is declared in a class.  Conventionally, it is a top-level (i.e. non-nested) `public` class, but that is not a requirement.  (A non-public class will work, and I think a static nested class will work too.)

How do you find the `main` method?

- Use `grep` or similar to search the source code of your application.
- Use your IDE's method search capability.
- Read the application's user documentation or launch script.
- Look for the `main` method in the index of the application's javadoc.

How does the `java` command find it?

It doesn't!  You specify the fully qualified class name of the class containing the `main` method you want to use on the `java` command line.  Alternatively, you can set the Main-Class attribute in a JAR file's manifest so that the user doesn't need to know the class name.

---

**UPDATE** - If you are looking for the code in the OpenJDK source tree that loads the entrypoint class, finds the main method and invokes it, it is all in "jdk8u/jdk/src/share/bin/java.c".  Happy reading.

Comment: Thank You Stephen! I'm also able to track till the libraries in source, I assume there is 2 native files name main.c and java.c is responsible for this action.

Comment: Ermm ... You've confused me now.  I thought you were looking for the `main` method of >> *your* Java application <<.  You won't find it in C source file.  It's a Java method ...

Comment: Pardon me! I'm just trying to understand how my main method is interpreted by my JVM. or internal mechanism how is it deciding only main method as my programs entry point.

Comment: Well that is not how a native English speaker would read / understand your question!

Comment: Yes i agree :) ! I'm still trying to understand, can you help me out here please?

Answer (score 0):

It's not defined anywhere as code (in the standard libraries).

The `JVM` expects to find it if you're running a class, and if it's not found you get an error. Therefore it's up to you to create a `public static void main(String[] args)` method if you want to run your class.

Answer (score 0):

main method is the entry point of an application in java. All the java classes are packaged as libraries which will be used in any application. So class files are used as references instead of separte executable. You can't execute the java source code separately because there won't be any main method definition in java source code.